# How to handle POST response using Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, post

I'm new to Java Servlet programming and have a question about how to handle POST response from other servers (not user's POST request) using Servlet programming.

Suppose my application needs to consult another server in order to process user's request. I need to

1. send an asynchronous `POST` request (i.e. specify a `redirect_uri` in the `POST` request body) to the other server;
2. handle the `POST` response from the other server;
3. present some result to the user.

I think I need one Servlet to handle user's request and send a `POST` request to the other server, and I need another Servlet (since the `POST` request is asynchronous) to handle the POST response from the other server. My specific questions are:

1. What's the best way to send a `POST` request in this case? For example, using `HttpUrlConnection`?
2. How to handle a `POST` response in a Servlet? It confused me because a servlet is supposed to handle "request" not "response" but in this case the incoming message is indeed a `POST` response from the other server. In particular, if you can point me the relevant API/method that would be really helpful. For example, in `doPost()`? How to get the `POST` response body? (I assume we can get it from `HttpServletRequest` object).

Thanks very much!
Yue

Comment: If you're waiting on the result of the POST to present something to the user, you should be doing it synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the term 'POST Response'.However may be you are talking about servlet chaining scenario if I understood your requirement correctly.

> Servlet Chaining means the output of one servlet act as a input to
>   another servlet. Servlet Aliasing allows us to invoke more than one
>   servlet in sequence when the URL is opened with a common servlet
>   alias. The output from first Servlet is sent as input to other Servlet
>   and so on. The Output from the last Servlet is sent back to the
>   browser. The entire process is called Servlet Chaining.

[Example of Servlet Chaining](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/example-of-servlet-chaining.html)

Comment: The other server is not maintained by me. Actually I misunderstood the protocol and the other server does send the POST response right after my Servlet sends the POST request. So the POST request is not handled asynchronously. In fact, currently there is no way to implement asynchronous POST request as ajay mentioned below. In summary, my misunderstand leads to this "no solution" question : ) Sorry about that.